# Android while driving logic

Tags: android, location

I want to practise my Android development skills by creating an app wich sets 2 locations. To make it more interesting, I only want to set them while I am driving / arrived. The first, startLocation is created when the user is faster than 19km/h. I get that at the onLocationChanged Event with FusedLocationApi from google.

But obviously, there is the question when to create the endLocation. My solution for that would be to run a handler if the speed is less then 19km/h and wait 2 minutes. If the speed doesnt get faster then 19km/h within 2 minutes the endLocation get set.

Having said that I would like to hear some other solutions for that problem.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the solution I used when I wrote a similar app 5 years ago.  Since then Google came out with activity detection, which determines if a user is walking, biking, or driving.  I'd just use that now.

Comment: I found this: https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-recognize-user-activity-with-activity-recognition--cms-25851 But I am already using the GoogleApiClient for FusedLocationApi to get locations. How would you combine this two Apis at once?

Comment: I achieved that by adding two times an API for googleClient.         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .addApi(ActivityRecognition.API)
                .build();

Answer (score 0):

Solution with handler that waits for 2 minutes is not the best, because 
by that time your activity might be destroyed.

You can schedule task using [Alarm Manager](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/scheduling-task-using-alarm-manager.html)
Or if you are using API 21+ the best option is [enter link description here](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidTaskScheduling/article.html)